# Best way to handle Insert/Update statements in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, deadlock, sql-insert

I have been working on design of new system and there is many situation where function will handle Insert/Update statements. Usually this kind of process is handled old fashion way using server side language to determine which query will be executed. There is few things that I would like to eliminate and improve. This way has a lot of redundant code where we repeat same code twice for Insert and Update. Also there is an issue in our old system where we have a tons of deadlock errors from the server. Our database has very poor design and that might be also one of the many factors why we have tons of these error messages. However, working on old legacy code I have learned what should be avoided and not to repeat the same exact mistakes. So here is example of the code that handles Insert/Update in my current application:

```
<cfif len(FORM.frm_id)>
    <cfquery name="updateTbl" datasource="#dns#">
        UPDATE Table1
        SET
            testdt = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.frm_testdt#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" maxlength="10" null="#!len(FORM.frm_testdt)#" />,
            location = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(FORM.frm_location)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500" null="#!len(trim(FORM.frmhs_location))#" />,
            testwhy = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(FORM.frm_testwhy)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" null="#!len(trim(FORM.frm_testwhy))#" />
       WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.frm_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
    </cfquery>
<cfelse>
    <cfquery name="insertTbl" datasource="#dns#">
       INSERT INTO Table1(
          testdt, location, testwhy
       )VALUES(
          <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.frm_testdt#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" maxlength="10" null="#!len(FORM.frm_testdt)#" />,
          <cfqueryparam value="#trim(FORM.frm_location)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500" null="#!len(trim(FORM.frmhs_location))#" />,
          <cfqueryparam value="#trim(FORM.frm_testwhy)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" null="#!len(trim(FORM.frm_testwhy))#" />
       ) 
       SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS RecID 
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

As you can see in example above a lot of redundancy but at the same time I'm not sure if it's efficient. Also there might be the reason why deadlocks occur so often. So I did some research and here is examples of what some people suggesting:

```
To avoid deadlocks and PK violations you can use something like this:

begin tran
if exists (select * from table with (updlock,serializable) where key = @key)
begin
   update table set ...
   where key = @key
end
else
begin
   insert into table (key, ...)
   values (@key, ...)
end
commit tran
```

OR

```
begin tran
   update table with (serializable) set ...
   where key = @key

   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin
      insert into table (key, ...) values (@key,..)
   end
commit tran
```

I'm not sure if those two examples are good practice and if there is any prons or cons to those two solutions. Then I have talked to one of th esenior level programmers and they suggested next.

```
-First use server side language (ColdFusion in our case) to determine if process is Insert or Update. 
-Then if it's insert do insert in the table with the blank data row.
-Run update and populate data.
```

In his opinion two examples that I showed above with SQL `beg if exists` are putting too much work in SQL and we should handle decision of insert update by server side language. He said that solution he provided will prevent redundancy (what is true) and also that is more efficient to update than insert data with SQL. For that reason inserting empty/blank row will save some time. i'm wondering which way to go and it's hard to decide. If anyone can help and provide some comment or example please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Why in the world does this person think that inserting a partial row and then updating it is faster than just inserting the whole row? That has an unbelievable amount of smell to it, like the backside of a horse. There is some merit in leveraging the front end to know if you need to insert or update. But in a well indexed table using exists is pretty painless, even with millions of rows. The problem is this question is both too broad and opinion based.

Comment: @SeanLange I was wondering since there is way too may answers/opinions and I'm not sure what is the best way to approach this situation.

Comment: Inserting a blank row first actually makes performance worse, not better. Inserting a new row involves rewriting data pages to accommodate that row, and then you update that row, which involves rewriting data pages *again*. If the row is in the middle and has variable-sized columns the problem becomes that much worse. It is never more efficient to insert-then-update as opposed to inserting the correct values right away. The actual solution to your problems will involve 1) reading up on how to properly diagnose and solve deadlocks and 2) ignoring the first person's advice with regards to SQL.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Do you have any opinion on second example that I ave provided with `begin tran` in SQL? Is that process something that you would recommend for inserting/updating rows?

Comment: It depends. (Don't you love answers like that?) Is there any chance of another session inserting a row with the same key? If so, the transaction and `SERIALIZABLE` hint are necessary, but if not, they're not, and they *might* help prevent deadlocks, but that depends crucially on what the deadlocks *are* (as in, which queries are deadlocking). If your actual, real problem is deadlocks, analyze those first before you start plugging in new code that may or may not fix things.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There might be multiple transaction Inserting/Updating records at the same time. I have uniqeidentifier as PK on my table. SO that should prevent Insert of the same key at the same time. There still might be the chance where users can be updating the same record at the same time. I'm not sure if that can cause any problems.